# jQuery - hide all rows that do not have value selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to hide table rows based on a display filter that corresponds to the selected value in each row.

**Display filter**

```
<select class="form-control" id="displayFilter">
  <option value="0" selected>all</option>
  <option value="1">Category A</option>
  <option value="2">Category B</option>
  <option value="3">Category C</option> 
</select>
```

I'm able to get the new value when it is changed:

```
$('#displayFilter').change(function () {
  console.log("Filter changed to: " + this.value);        
});
```

**Example rows**

```
<tr data-id="1">
  <td>Product A</td>
  <td>
    <select class="form-control">
      <option value="1" selected>Category A</option>
      <option value="2">Category B</option>
      <option value="3">Category C</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr data-id="2">
  <td>Product B</td>
  <td>
    <select class="form-control">
      <option value="1">Category A</option>
      <option value="2" selected>Category B</option>
      <option value="3">Category C</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a conditional JavaScript like this:

1. If the value is show all, just show all the `<tr>`s and stop.
2. If not, go through all the `.form-control` inside the table.

   1. If the value matches, show the corresponding `<tr>`.
   2. If not, hide it.

**Code:**

```
$(function () {
  $('#displayFilter').change(function () {
    that = this;
    if (this.value == 0)
      $("tr").show();
    else
    $("table .form-control").each(function () {
      if (this.value == that.value)
        $(this).closest("tr").show();
      else
        $(this).closest("tr").hide();
    });
  });
});
```

```js
$(function () {
  $('#displayFilter').change(function () {
    that = this;
    if (this.value == 0)
      $("table tr").show();
    else
      $("table .form-control").each(function () {
        if (this.value == that.value)
          $(this).closest("tr").show();
        else
          $(this).closest("tr").hide();
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="displayFilter">
  <option value="0" selected>all</option>
  <option value="1">Category A</option>
  <option value="2">Category B</option>
  <option value="3">Category C</option> 
</select>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-id="1">
      <td>Product A</td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control">
          <option value="1" selected>Category A</option>
          <option value="2">Category B</option>
          <option value="3">Category C</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-id="2">
      <td>Product B</td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control">
          <option value="1">Category A</option>
          <option value="2" selected>Category B</option>
          <option value="3">Category C</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Or just this (put classes on TRs):

```
$(function () {
  $('#displayFilter').change(function() {
    $('tr').hide(); // Hide all
    $('tr.' + this.val() ).show(); // Show only the TR you selected
  });
});
```

Like on [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xezz2jkg/).

Comment: `ID`s cannot contain duplicate values. `:)`

Comment: Sure but when I need to do something like this I usually do like `<tr id="parentId+thisTRId">` so the IDs won't be duplicated.

Comment: Kindly check the question and try to apply your solution for that. ps: Not my downvote. But just telling you, it won't apply! Your solution doesn't work bro.

Comment: Like this: [https://jsfiddle.net/xezz2jkg/](https://jsfiddle.net/xezz2jkg/)

Comment: Bro, you are right... but you are using classes instead of ids right? So that works fine... So if you replace id with classes, your answer will be right.